# No método Object.assign(), e resultado visualmente é o mesmo, independente se é atribuito o [{}] ou não

Tags: javascript

```js
let obj = [
    {
        id:1,
        nome:'Tony Stark'
    },

    {
        id: 2,
        nome: 'Steve Rogers'
    }
];

let clone = Object.assign([{}], obj);
let clone2 = Object.assign(obj);
console.log(clone);
console.log(clone2);
```

Comment: Qual a sua dúvida?

Comment: Qual a diferença de incluir o [{}] no Object.assign sendo que sem ele o resultado é o mesmo?

Answer (score 0):

No `clone` você passou `[{}]` como origem, o interpretador vai entender como um objeto array vazio e preencher com o novo objeto.

No `clone2` você nada fez senão criar uma referência para o primeiro objeto. Se você fizer alteração no `obj` ela será refletida para o `clone2`. É uma "forma incorreta" ou não ideal de se fazer, é o mesmo que fazer `clone2 = obj`.

Observe a implementação da função Object.assign():

> **Sintaxe**

Object.assign(destino, ...origens)

> Parâmetros

**destino** - O objeto destino.

**origens** - Um ou mais objetos de origem.

> Citação

O objeto 'destino' será retornado.

Referência: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign